# Elegant way to check whether node already in graph

Tags: java, loops, graph

I want to check whether a node with a certain ID is already in my graph or whether I have to create a new object. At the moment I am doing it with the following code:

```
// at this point I have the attributes for the node I need

String id = getIdOfNeededNode(); // The id is used to search for the node in the graph

// now I have to search for the node in the graph
Node node = new Node("dummy_id"); // This is the line I don't like; 
                                  // I would prefer not to have a dummy node
                                  // but the compiler will then complain that the node might not be initialized 

boolean alreadyCreated = false;

for(Node r : graph.getVertices()){ // search for the node with this id in the graph
    if (r.getId().equals(portId)){
        node = r;
        alreadyCreated = true;
        break;
        }
    }

if (!alreadyCreated) {     // create a new object if the node was not found
    node = new Resource(portId);
    createdPortResources.add(port);
    }

// In the remainder of the program, I am working with the node object which then is in the graph
```

The fact that I am creating a dummy node that is just a placeholder is really ugly. Please let me know how I can solve this problem in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can just do this `Node node = null;`

But in general, just keep a map from the portIds to the nodes.
When you want to make that check, just consult that map.
It will be way easier and faster.

Comment: "Don't set a flag; set the data." - `alreadyCreated` can then be eliminated as a check for a null node suffices.